# Sample size over whiskers of boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I want to display "n = (n)" over the whiskers of each of my boxplots. I have figured out how to put these labels over the top of each box (q75) using fivenum, but I can't get them working above the whisker. Above the whiskers is better because my plots are very cluttered.

Here I've reproduced the plots using mtcars
Edit: mtcars has no significant outliers, but my dataset does. That's why the label needs to be on top of the whisker, and not just on the highest data point.

sidenote: I am working with a lot of outliers and want to take them out of the display. GGplot can do this, but it will still include outliers in the axis, which gives me a very "zoomed out" plot. My workaround for this is included. I've used the base boxplot function to calculate the highest whisker, and used coord_cartesian to set the upper limit just above that.

```
> data("mtcars")
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> 
> d = data.table(mtcars)
> 
> give.n <- function(x){
+   return(data.frame(y = fivenum(x)[4],
+                     label = paste("n =",length(x))))
+ }
> 
> p1 <- boxplot(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars, outline=FALSE,
+               plot=0)
> p1stats <- p1$stats[5,]
> head(p1stats)
[1] 33.9 21.4 19.2
> upperlim <- max(p1$stats, na.rm = TRUE) * 1.05
>   
> p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) +
+     geom_boxplot() +
+ stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", vjust=-.5)
> 
> p <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, upperlim))
```

I tried changing this function (which works):

```
> give.n <- function(x){
+   return(data.frame(y = fivenum(x)[4],
+                     label = paste("n =",length(x))))
+ }
```

To this, using the 5th row of p1 stats (the upper whiskers):

```
give.n <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y = p1stats,
                    label = paste("n =",length(x))))
}
```

But that returns this:
[bad plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Z6s.png)

How do I get this to display the label on only the correct whisker point for each box?

PS - My apologies, I'm unfamiliar with posting here but I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay scratch that last attempt. I figured it out. boxplot.stats and geom_boxplot calculate quartile stats differently, and that skews everything in small sample sizes. We can call the actual stats geom_boxplot uses with ggplot_build.

This is how it's done, son. First, make your plot, like above, I called it p.
Now calculate sample size for each x variable

```
samp <- count(mtcars, cyl)
```

now retrieve the data from the plot using ggplot_build

```
ggstat <- ggplot_build(p)$data
ggwhisk1 <- ggstat[[1]]$ymax
```

now combine that with the sample size, and call that data in geom_text

```
ggwhisk2 <- data.frame(samp, whisk = ggwhisk1)
p <- p + geom_text(data = ggwhisk2, size = 2,
aes(x = cyl, y = whisk, label = paste0("n =", n), vjust = -.5))
```

Voila!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ggplot solution with dpylr:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, group=cyl)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text(data=mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(top = max(mpg), n=n()), aes(x=cyl, y=top, label= paste0("n = ", n)), nudge_y=1)
```

[image]

EDIT

There's probably a more concise way, but I think this works.  I edited a data point for cyl=8 for emphasis:

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, group=cyl)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text(data=mtcars %>% 
              group_by(cyl) %>% 
              summarise(q3 = quantile(mpg, 0.75),
                        q1 = quantile(mpg, 0.25),
                        iqr = q3 - q1,
                        top = min(q3 + 1.5*iqr, max(mpg)), 
                        n=n()), 
            aes(x=cyl, y=top, label= paste0("n = ", n)), nudge_y=1)
```

[image]

Comment: So this works by putting the label on the highest value for each box/group, but not on the whisker. In a dataset with large outliers, they will be off-screen.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  Edited the post to account for this.

Comment: Thank you. This is nearly perfect, but there's another issue. It works for any group with an even sample size. When there's an odd sample size, the variable "top" returns q3 + 1.5*iqr, instead of returning the maximum level within that range. Trying to figure this out.



Edit: so i guess the issue is that q3 +1.5*iqr isn't a datapoint. geom_boxplot whiskers are the max point in the dataset that is less than q3 + 1.5* iqr. This is why I was trying to get the stat out of my "dummy" boxplot that I used to define the y range.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: see the comment below and my other answer!

Okay I figured it out using the format of Alan's answer. It needed boxplot.stats to get the correct whisker calculation:

```
geom_text(data=mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
            summarise(n = n(),
                      boxstats = boxplot.stats(mpg)[1],
                      whisker = boxstats[5]),
            aes(x=cyl, y=whisker, label=paste0("n =", n)))
```

Comment: This still isn't perfect. Turns out geom_boxplot and boxplot.stats calculate the quartiles differently. I believe one includes the median and the other does not. This is the difference between QUARTILE.INC and QUARTILE.EXC in excel. Still works pretty well, but some of the labels might be slightly off of the whisker, especially in low sample sizes